# How do I create a menu and assign it to a location using a hook in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, hook, action

In my theme, I am adding a menu upon theme activation using

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mycustom_register_menu' );
function mycustom_register_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'somelocation', __( 'My Menu') );
}
```

I added the location in my theme's header.php, now all that's left is to create a menu in the dashbaord and assign it to that location. It works perfectly when I do so manually.

My question is, how can I automate it? so when the theme is activated and "My Menu" is added as a location, a menu with a certain name is created and assigned to that location? Is there a hook for that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Creating Custom Navigation Menus in WordPress Theme

   ```
   function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
     register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
   }
   add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
   ```
2. If you want to add more than one new navigation menu location, then you would need to use a code like this:

   ```
   function wpb_custom_new_menu() {`enter code here`
     register_nav_menus(
       array(
         'my-custom-menu' => __( 'My Custom Menu' ),
         'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
       )
     );
   }
   add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
   ```
3. Displaying Custom Navigation Menus in WordPress Themes

   ```
   <?php
     wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu', 
        'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) ); 
   ?>
   ```

Comment: If you read my question, you'll see I already used that hook and created the menu location etc. This doesn't answer my question, and the wpbeginner.com article from which you took the code is probably the first results of every google search for "adding menus in wordpress"...